# Can $in and $or replace each other in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

Can $in and $or replace each other in MongoDB?

```
db.restaurants.find(
{
  "borough" :{$in :["Staten Island","Queens","Bronx","Brooklyn"]}},
  {
    "restaurant_id" : 1,
    "name":1,"borough":1,
    "cuisine" :1
  }
);


db.restaurants.find(
{ 
"borough": "Bronx" , 
  $or : [
          { "cuisine" : "American " },
          { "cuisine" : "Chinese" }
        ] 
} 
);
```

Here I observe that both these queries require us to choose from some options:

Does it make sense to replace $in in the first query with $or as follows:

```
db.restaurants.find(
{ $or: [{ borough: 'Staten Island',
          borough: 'Queens',
          borough: 'Bronx',
          borough: 'Brooklyn' }],

  { _id : 1,
    name: 1,
    borough : 1,
    cuisine : 1
  }
 })
```

Are $in and $or replaceable?

Update:
I tried to use two queries in a hope to get identical results:

Why is the second query selecting two rows of status 'D' only?

```
> db.inventory.find( {status : { $in: [ 'A', 'D'] }}, {item:1, status: 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45087"), "item" : "journal", "status" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45088"), "item" : "notebook", "status" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45089"), "item" : "paper", "status" : "D" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d4508a"), "item" : "planner", "status" : "D" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d4508b"), "item" : "postcard", "status" : "A" }
>
>
> db.inventory.find( {$or: [ {status: 'A', status: 'D'} ] }, {item:1, status: 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45089"), "item" : "paper", "status" : "D" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d4508a"), "item" : "planner", "status" : "D" }
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their official documentation itself [or-versus-in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/index.html#or-versus-in) :

> When using $or with  that are equality checks for the
>   value of the same field, use the $in operator instead of the $or
>   operator.

If you've docs like below :

```
[
  {
    "price": 100
  },
  {
    "price": 200
  },
  {
    "price": 300
  },
  {
    "price": 400
  },
  {
    "price": 500
  }
]
```

If you wanted to get docs where `price` is equal to `100` or `500`, query like :

```
db.collection.find({ price: { $in: [ 100, 500 ] } })
```

By doing like above, query is simple & clean. You can also use `$or` instead of `$in` but why would you loose shorthand notation and try to make your query look bulky by adding more objects of same field again and again ?

By default if you wanted to do logical `OR` on two different operators you would use `$or`, But when to use `$or` on same field :

```
db.collection.find({ $or: [ { price: { $lt: 200 } }, { price: { $gt: 400 } } ] })
```

As like above when you've multiple different conditions to match on same field you'll use it.

These two queries yield same result when executed but when you use `$in` - if input values are straight numbers or can be strings or other types where input values will exactly match with values of `price` field in docs, but when you use `$or` you're checking for different conditions on same field.

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jLfzZ_d0s11)

Comment: Your answer is more detailed. Yielding my answer to favor yours. +1

Comment: I have updated the question. Please add the updated answer.

Comment: `The $or operator performs a logical OR operation on an array of two or more <expressions> and selects the documents that satisfy at least one of the <expressions>.` Does this mean that $or is bound to present results which satisfy only one condition? That's why it showed results with status 'D' only in my updated question?

Comment: I understood it. Thanks.