# Mongoose aggregation: MongoError: unknown operator: $or

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to perform a query on a mongo database with three variables: age, job, and location as an option. I use Node and Express on the server side.

I have written this:

```js
router.post("/search", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { jobs, minAge, maxAge, location, maxDistance } = req.body;
   // jobs = ["Tech", "Sales"], minAge=45, maxAge = 62, location=[1.23, 4.56], maxDistance=10000 
    if (!location) {
      const user = User.aggregate([
        {$match: {
            jobs: { $or: jobs },
            age: { $gte: minAge, $lte: maxAge },
          }},
      ]).lean()
       return res.json({user})
      });
    }
 
    const user = User.aggregate([
     { $match: {
      job: { $or: job },
      age: { $gte: minAge, $lte: maxAge }
      },
        $geoNear: {
          near: { type: "Point", coordinates: location.coordinates },
          distanceField: "dist.calculated",
          maxDistance,
        },
      },
    ]).lean();
    return res.json({ user });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.json({ errorType: "search" });
  }
});
```

In case it might be helpful, here is the User Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    age: { type: Number, min: 18 },
    job: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["Tech", "Product", "Marketing", "Sales", "HR", "Other"],
    },
    location: {
      type: { type: String, enum: ["Point"] },
      coordinates: { type: [Number] },
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

userSchema.index({ age: 1, job: 1, location: "2dsphere" });

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

The error is `MongoError: unknown operator: $or`. How to properly retrieve an array of users that match the conditions expressed in the query?

Comment: According to my understanding, you need to match the `jobs` from an `array`. Then you can use `$in` instead of `$or`

Comment: I need to return users whose job is one of the jobs defined in the query's array.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 : You need to replace `job: { $or: job }` with `job: { $in: job }` to get desired result, also here `near: { type: "Point", coordinates: location.coordinates }` isn't that `coordinates: location` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `job: { $or: job }` with `job: { $in: job }` cause [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html) query operator validates a field's value against an array and get the documents if at least one of the element in the array matches with the field *Vs* [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/index.html) logical operator takes in two expressions not the values and get the documents where at least one expressions is satisfied.

**$in :**

```
// jobs = ["Tech", "Sales"]

jobs: { $in: jobs }
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bjg82qv_zUX)

**$or :**

```
{ $or: [ {jobs : 'Tech'} , {jobs : 'Sales'} ] }
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KxPeHI94Qnh)

As you're just validating against an array on same field you don't need `$or` operator a simple `$in` should work just fine. Moreover in `$geoNear` you might need to replace `coordinates: location.coordinates` with `coordinates: location` - I believe it's a typo.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 : If you wanted to read more on difference, check this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/61948578/7237613

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I highly appreciate your help. However, it only works without the geonear operator. I made sure to add dummy data in a range of 1km from my geo query. Yet, I receive "undefined". Yes, it was a typo, I send the location as [1.11, 2.22]. Also, what is the most efficient way to exclude the user doing the request from the result? Adding a _id: { $not: [user.id]} or doing a simple javascript filter once the results are here?

Comment: @DoneDeal0 : I've not used `$geoNear` anytime, Please post a new question on it, someone can help you. But prefer to get less data from DB if possible, So in this case : `_id` field is auto-indexed doing a simple filter(`$match`) on `_id` is quick & easy rather than getting docs to .Js & iterating over to remove unnecessary documents go ahead with DB query..

Answer (score 0):

[$or is an expression-level operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/), not a field-level operator. The field-level equivalent of $or is [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).